# PDO fetch multiple records from database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, fetch

I am writing a pretty basic piece of code to fetch one or (in most cases) multiple rows from a mysql database.

```
function getschema($mysqli){
    $id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $query = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT a.naam
                            FROM schemes AS a, aankoop AS b
                            WHERE b.aankoop_username_id = :userid && b.aankoop_schema_id = a.id");
    $query->bind_param(':userid', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->execute();
    $result = $query->fetchAll();
    echo ($result);
}
```

I get the user id from the session and pull the data with the query in the prepared statement. 
This statement is correct. I tried it in phpmyadmin and it returns the correct values.

Now I want to use this function in my HTML like so...

```
<?php echo getschema($mysqli); ?>
```

But my code does not return a thing, it even messes up the layout of my html page where I want to show the code.

I think it probably is something with the fetchAll command.  I also tried the `PDO::Fetch_ASSOC` but that did not work either.

In addition, I cannot see the php errors, even when they are enabled in the php.ini file.

Comment: @AbraCadaver why you posted this as comment not the answer?

Comment: @AbraCadaver, do you mean asign it as a value to a textarea or do you mean something else? I know it will be an array so i have to loop through it in my html page?

Comment: Look at your code very carefully; what doesn't belong together? Checking for errors would have told you that. Plus, which API are you using to connect with in the first place? Plus, you're running this inside a custom function.

Comment: we also don't know whether or not the session was started

Comment: @Fred-ii-, the session has started, i'm able to echo it's contents on a test page. Further i'm using the mysqli api to connect with the database and I finaly was able to print out the error's and the one i'm getting is Call to undefined function getschema() when i call the function on my test page:  foreach(getschema($mysqli) as $row) {
    echo $row['naam'];}. Also i made a small change to the query: && became AND, not that this matters in the execution i guess.

Comment: *"i'm using the mysqli api to connect with"* - there are 3, which one? `mysqli_`? `mysql_`? PDO? Edit: Ok `mysqli_` got it.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, i'm using mysqli_.
This is my connection string: $mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);

Comment: well you're mixing them and you can't do that. It seems I'm the only one who spotted that.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, could you point out to me where i'm mixing the pdo and mysqli statements?

Comment: `WHERE b.aankoop_username_id = :userid` and `bind_param(':userid', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT)` read up on it http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: oh and `fetchAll` too. I edited my comment above with a link to. That ought to get you started ;-) question should be closed as a duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what's going on; you're mixing MySQL APIs/functions and those do not intermix.

Replace the `:userid` (PDO) bind in `b.aankoop_username_id = :userid` with a `?` placeholder

```
b.aankoop_username_id = ?
```

Then this line:

```
$query->bind_param(':userid', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Replace `:userid` by `$id` and remove `, PDO::PARAM_INT` but adding `i`

```
$query->bind_param("i", $id);
```

Sidenote: Make sure that column is `int` type. If not, use `s` instead of `i`.

Replace the line for `fetchAll` with the loop as outlined in AbraCadaver's  answer.

- You can't mix MySQL APIs/function, read the following on Stack:
- [Can I mix MySQL APIs in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php)

Read up on mysqli with prepared statements and how it works:

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Checking for errors would have outlined the errors.

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Thank you, i'm finaly able to do a var dump from my array. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `echo ($result);` do `return $result;` in your function.

Then to use it you have to loop over the array of rows and echo the column that you want:

```
foreach(getschema($mysqli) as $row) {
    echo $row['naam'];
}
```

Or assign the function return to a variable and loop over that:

```
$rows = getschema($mysqli);
```

Comment: i'm trying it with the foreach solution you provided. But for some reason, my layout is ruined that way. I put this output in a javascript tab, but i cannot open it anymore when i put the code in.

Comment: when I make a new php file and include all the necessary config file. I call the getschema function with the code you provided but i can't get any output lines on the screen. Do you maby know what this causes? I think my pdo statement is correct but i don't know for sure.

Comment: There's a problem with OP's code and it looks a bit like *rum & coke*. See what they're doing? They're using the wrong ingredients ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Well I'll be damned.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Yeah. I stumbled on the question earlier and thought you may haven't been around, so I thought I'd put in an addition to yours.